# Make mat-icon use svg by default

Tags: angular, angular-material

When using `<mat-icon>info</mat-icon>` it defaults to the font based icon (that I have not loaded). Is it possible to make it just behave like if I wrote `<mat-icon svgIcon="info"></mat-icon>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any kind of material customization provided for that. What you can easily do is create a component in your app:
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-icon',
  templateUrl: './custom-icon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-icon.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CustomIconComponent {
  @Input()
  iconName!: string;
}
```

and template:

```
<mat-icon [svgIcon]="iconName"></mat-icon>
```

Then you can use it across your app like:

```
<app-custom-icon [iconName]="help"></app-custom-icon>
```

Comment: Yeah, guess that'd be the best alternative than. So I probably just go with the svgIcon property.